# where exactly PIG stores its relations

Tags: apache-pig

i am in a big confusion with the below two statements.
1) where exactly LOAD statement stores this relation(student), is it on hdfs/PIG internal storage/local machine ???

```
example : student = LOAD 'HDFS:/student' using PigStorage(',');
```

2) if i try to DUMP student; then it takes almost 30-40 sec to display result where as LOAD statement takes 1-2 sec.... if we are trying to retrieve data from pig internal storage then why is this delay ??

would be grateful if anyone can clear this doubts(preferably the flow of execution). thanks in adv.

my env: i am using VM for learning purpose.

Answer (score 1):

The `LOAD` does not store the data but it is just a pointer to the file.
When `LOAD` statement is executed, no `MapReduce` task is executed.

It is only after the `DUMP` or `STORE` statement that a `MapReduce` job is initiated. 
We see our data in the output and we can confirm that the data has been loaded successfully.

`DUMP` take time as it disables multi-query execution and and slows down execution. (If you have included `DUMP` statements in your scripts for debugging purposes, you should remove them.)

If you want to store any data then can use the `STORE` command.

Comment: thanks alot for the reply. by pointer to the file, u mean data still resides on HDFS ?? and LOAD command creates an instance of that file to process in Grunt shell ??

Comment: yes.. the data will reside in the HDFS if you are running the pig in mapreduce mode and on local if it is running in local mode

Comment: As long as there is no dump or store statement, nothing is actually executed. Only when store or dump is requested, Pig will generate an execution plan (map-reduce job) and run it.